# Strange behaviour when populating php array

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I make a class that implements Iterator in PHP. This class expose an "records" property that is define as :

```
private $records = [];
```

In the body of the class, make a method to populate the array :

```
    /**
    * Add an item to the activeRecord collection
    * @param IActiveRecord $activeRecord
    */
   public function set(IActiveRecord $activeRecord){
    echo "Add" . $activeRecord->id . " to collection<br>\n";
    $this->records[] = $activeRecord;
    echo $this . "<br>\n";
   }
```

The statement echo $this refers to a __toString() method that humanize array content :

```
    /**
 * Humanize class
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString(): string {
    $output = "Number of activeRecords : " . $this->size() . "<br>\n";

    foreach($this as $record) {
        $output .= "id : " . $record->id . "<br>\n";
    }

    return $output;
}
```

When i populate the collection from a query result, i got :

```
Add 1 to collection<br>
Number of activeRecords : 1<br>
id : 1<br>
<br>
Add 2 to collection<br>
Number of activeRecords : 2<br>
id : 2<br>
id : 2<br>
<br>
```

As you can see, first iteration populate with id = 1, but the second iteration add id = 2 and replace first element by id = 2 too...

I have no idea of this strange behaviour... Iterator methods are correctly implemented (i think) :

```
    /**
 *
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see Iterator::current()
 */
public function current(){
    return $this->records[$this->index];
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see Iterator::next()
 */
public function next() {
    $this->index++;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see Iterator::key()
 */
public function key(){
    return $this->index;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see Iterator::valid()
 */
public function valid(){
    return $this->index < count($this->records) ? true : false;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see Iterator::rewind()
 */
public function rewind(){
    $this->index = 0;
}
```

EDIT 1 :
activeRecord are objects that come from a Controller :

```
    /**
 *
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @see \wp\Database\SQL\Select::selectBy()
 */
public function selectBy(){

    $this->statement = $this->entity->selectBy();

    if ($this->statement !== false){
        $this->statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        while($data = $this->statement->fetch()){
            $record = $this->entity->getActiveRecordInstance();
            $record->hydrate($data);
            $this->activeRecords->set($record);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

In this method, $this->entity->getActiveRecordInstance() is :

```
    /**
 * Return new ActiveRecord instance
 * @return \App\Entities\Promoteurs\PromoteursActiveRecord
 */
public function getActiveRecordInstance(){
    return new ActiveRecord($this->columns);    
}
```

So, i'm sure that the ActiveRecord populated is a new object every iteration.

Comment: Did you modify the value of first IActiveRecord after you pushed it to `$records`? I mean some code like [this](https://ideone.com/kOM1Ys)

Comment: I don't see any issues here. Check the part where you call the `set()` method.

Comment: Can you show the code which output the result?

Comment: activeRecord are both new activeRecord object that are instanciated in a loop through PDO::statement.

Comment: Think that @Daniel1147 give me a way to debug this strange behaviour... Maybe my activeRecord are in conflict

Comment: Instead of `$this->records[] = $activeRecord;`, use `$this->records[] = $activeRecord->id;` and see what will happen. Change `$output .= "id : " . $record->id . "<br>\n";` to `$output .= "id : " . $record . "<br>\n";` too.

Comment: I wrote a class Records with iterator functions exactly the same as yours and worked fine. [code](https://ideone.com/UfRljB)

Comment: Thx all... I investigated deeper my class hierarchy and @Daniel1147 was right, the loop i used to populate the array replaced object instead of instancied a new one. Finally, i refactored my classes and all's ok